# Returning ROW NUMBER of Item when in process of creation of it

Tags: sql, hana

I've created query which returns Row Number of Item master data according to ItemCode dinamically:

```
SELECT "ROWNUM" From(

SELECT * From( SELECT "ItemCode", row_number() OVER (Order by "CreateDate") AS "ROWNUM"

FROM OITM)

WHERE "ItemCode"=$[OITM.ItemCode])
```

but, I have one problem with Items, which are in process of creation. As I guess, at this time row number is not assigned.

Is it possible somehow to get the Row number for item which is in process of creation?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "in the process of creation" mean?  This will return values that are in the table, but not other values.

Comment: I'm creating Item in SAP Business One. in the creation process, row is not added on the table yet. I thought about using IFNULL and increment last row number+1